# Symfony returning json from entity repository using JMS Serializer

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I using Symfony 4.4 with [JMS Serializer Bundle](https://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle) and i create simply method in controller:

```
$serializer = $this->container->get('serializer');
$response = $serializer->serialize($unitRepository->findAll(), 'json', ['groups' => ['normal']]);
    
return new JsonResponse($response);
```

But return array without data like:

```
"[[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]"
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thx all for help :)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the `normal` group annotation to your Unit entity properties you would like to see in the response.

[Documentation here](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies#creating-different-views-of-your-objects)

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

class Unit
{
    /** @Groups({"Default", "normal"}) */
    protected $id;
}
```

Or not specifying any group like this should return all available properties:

```
$response = $serializer->serialize($unitRepository->findAll(), 'json');
```